# Error: Can't set headers after they are sent. NodeJS used async function

Tags: node.js, rest, express, http

I faced to a little problem which blocks me. I'm working on authentication user service for my app used Node.js. I'm working on a PUT user route and need to compare the old and new password used bcrypt.

Sense adding a comparative `try/catch` I'm getting the following error:

> Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

```
app.put(`/users/:email`, checkAuthenticated, envisionDuplicateEmails, async (req, res) => {
  const accountEmail = req.params.email
  body = req.body
  const user = users.find((user) => user.email === accountEmail)
  const index = users.indexOf(user)

  if (!user) {
    res.status(500).send('Account not found.');
  } else {

    try {
      if (await bcrypt.compare(body.password, user.password)) {
        body.password = user.password
      } else {
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(body.password, 10)
        body.password = hashedPassword
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return res.status(500).send('Internal server error');
    }

    const updatedAccount = { ...user, ...body }
    users[index] = updatedAccount
    res.redirect('/')
  }
})
```

utility functions:

```
function checkAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next()
  }
  res.redirect('/login')
}

function envisionDuplicateEmails(req, res, next) {
  accountEmail = req.params.email
  bodyEmail = req.body.email

  if (bodyEmail) {
    if (bodyEmail != accountEmail) {
      checkEmailExist(req, res, next)
    }
  }
  return next()
}

function checkEmailExist(req, res, next) {
  const accountEmail = req.body.email
  const getAccount = users.find((user) => user.email === accountEmail)

  if (getAccount === undefined) {
  } else {
    return res.status(500).send({ 'message': 'Account email already exist' })
  }
  return next()
}
```

Thanks for help :P

Comment: Just a side note, if you're accepting emails from the public, the characters that can appear in valid emails makes receiving it as a URL parameter troublesome!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to re-execute the `res.status(500)` twice.

In your try/catch clause, just add the `return` keyword like that:

```js
try {
    if (await bcrypt.compare(body.password, user.password)) {
      body.password = user.password
    } else {
      const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(body.password, 10)
      body.password = hashedPassword
    }
  } catch (e) {
    // I've added the return keyword here
    return res.status(500).send('Internal server error');
  }
```

Now, when your try/catch catch an error, the code not continue and stop here.

Comment: Thanks for responding, adding the return still raise the same error :/

Comment: The error occurs only since you have added the try/catch clause ?

Comment: Since adding the if/else statement inside the try/catch. If i will remove the try/catch clause I will also get the error.

Comment: What the content of your two functions ? (checkAuthenticated and envisionDuplicateEmails)
Maybe the error comes from there...

Comment: Hey man, just adding the util functions to my question. I still don't think they cause the problem since the PUT function works just fine if i will remove the try/catch content.

Comment: You said "if I will remove the try/catch I will also get the error"...
So, to be sure, just try to add return before your `checkEmailExist(req, res, next)` call.

Comment: What I have meant is that if I remove the hole try/catch with it's content everything will work just fine. On the other hand, if I will remove the try/catch statement (getting out the if/else content) I will get the same error. 

P.S: adding a return to checkEmailExist doesn't help :(

Comment: If you move the if condition after the try/catch, in the try clause, after the first statement ? It's the same ?

Comment: Yes the same unfortunately

Comment: Check if the try clause catch error by adding a debug print before `res.status(500)...`

Comment: It does not catch any error (related to the code I posted). 

The error points the last line of the code res.redirect('/'). But since the statement inside the try invoke the error I really don't think that's the problematic line.

Again thanks a lot guys. Appreciate.

Comment: A new evidence: The error occurs only if I change the user email address. Changing a password or name will work just fine

Comment: I see just a little mistakes in your code, you check if the user exists at the end, after the try/catch clause, but you use `user.password` inside your try/catch...

Comment: It's a nice one, BUT still does not solve my main problem.

Comment: Uhh... I play my last card, try to remove the status before `send`. I'm in the blur I admit that I dry a little there...

Comment: I solved the problem by implementing the checkEmailExist in envisionDuplicateEmails. But I don't know why passing at checkEmailExist function solved a "Can't set headers" issue (it doesn't enter the res.status(500) in that function).

Comment: Maybe you can just add one middleware in the route functions... I will know it for the next time !